# How to prevent sprites from going on top of each other

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So I'm not that experienced with Pygame and I'd like to how to prevent enemies from overlapping. I've tried a few methods with little to no success. I'd like to hear your ideas on how I could do such a thing. I think a good idea would be through collision detection. Yet I am not quite sure how that would work.

Here's the enemies code:

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def draw(self):
        global characterradius, characterradius1, characterradius2, characterradius3, characterradius4, characterradius5
        global characterradius6, characterradius7, estanding, emoveup, emovedown, emoveleft, emoveright, enemyradiusshow
        global eradius1, eradius2, eradius3, eradius4

        self.enemyradiusshow = True
        self.estanding = False
        emoveup = False
        emovedown = False
        emoveleft = False
        emoveright = False

        if moveup:
            self.y += speed
        if movedown:
            self.y -= speed
        if moveleft:
            self.x += speed
        if moveright:
            self.x -= speed

        enemyhitbox = pygame.Rect(self.x + 6, self.y + 5, 50, 80)
        self.enemyhitbox = pygame.Rect(self.x + 6, self.y + 5, 50, 80)
        enemyhitboxvisible = True
        self.enemyhitboxvisible = False
        playerradiusvisible = False

        if self.enemyhitboxvisible:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (self.x + 6, self.y + 5, 50, 80))
        if enemyhitboxvisible:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (self.x + 6, self.y + 5, 50, 80))

        if playerradiusvisible:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (80, 200, 50), (character_x - 180, character_y - 180, 150.5, 150.5))
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (200, 80, 50), (character_x + 80, character_y - 180, 150.5, 150.5))
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (80, 50, 200), (character_x - 180, character_y + 90, 150.5, 150.5))
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (200, 150, 50), (character_x + 80, character_y + 90, 150.5, 150.5))

            pygame.draw.rect(win, (150, 150, 50), (character_x - 180, character_y - 30, 150.5, 120))
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (200, 70, 50), (character_x + 80, character_y - 30, 150.5, 120))
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (50, 150, 200), (character_x - 30, character_y - 180, 110, 150.5))
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (50, 150, 200), (character_x - 30, character_y + 90, 110, 150.5))

        characterradius = pygame.Rect(character_x - 180, character_y - 180, 150.5, 150.5)
        characterradius1 = pygame.Rect(character_x + 80, character_y - 180, 150.5, 150.5)
        characterradius2 = pygame.Rect(character_x - 180, character_y + 90, 150.5, 150.5)
        characterradius3 = pygame.Rect(character_x + 80, character_y + 90, 150.5, 150.5)
        character_hitbox = pygame.Rect(character_x + 80, character_y + 90, 150.5, 150.5)

        characterradius4 = pygame.Rect(character_x - 180, character_y - 30, 150.5, 120)
        characterradius5 = pygame.Rect(character_x + 80, character_y - 30, 150.5, 120)
        characterradius6 = pygame.Rect(character_x - 30, character_y - 180, 110, 150.5)
        characterradius7 = pygame.Rect(character_x - 30, character_y + 90, 110, 150.5)

        self.enemyspeed = 1

        if characterradius.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.x += self.enemyspeed
            self.y += self.enemyspeed
            emoveleft = True
        if characterradius1.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.x -= self.enemyspeed
            self.y += self.enemyspeed
            emoveright = True
        if characterradius2.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.x += self.enemyspeed
            self.y -= self.enemyspeed
            emoveleft = True
        if characterradius3.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.x -= self.enemyspeed
            self.y -= self.enemyspeed
            emoveright = True
        if characterradius4.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.x += self.enemyspeed
            emoveleft = True
        if characterradius5.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.x -= self.enemyspeed
            emoveright = True
        if characterradius6.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.y += self.enemyspeed
            emovedown = True
        if characterradius7.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.y -= self.enemyspeed
            emoveup = True

        if emoveup:
            win.blit(zombieupimage, (self.x, self.y))
            self.emovedown = False
            self.emoveleft = False
            self.emoveright = False
            self.emoveup = True
        if emovedown:
            win.blit(zombieimage, (self.x - 5.5, self.y - 4))
            self.emovedown = True
            self.emoveleft = False
            self.emoveright = False
            self.emoveup = False
        if emoveleft:
            win.blit(zombieleftimage, (self.x, self.y))
            self.emovedown = False
            self.emoveleft = True
            self.emoveright = False
            self.emoveup = False
        if emoveright:
            win.blit(zombierightimage, (self.x, self.y))
            self.emovedown = False
            self.emoveleft = False
            self.emoveright = True
            self.emoveup = False

        if not emoveup:
            self.estanding = True
        if not emovedown:
            self.estanding = True
        if not emoveleft:
            self.estanding = True
        if not emoveright:
            self.estanding = True

        if characterradius.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.estanding = False
        if characterradius1.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.estanding = False
        if characterradius2.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.estanding = False
        if characterradius3.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.estanding = False
        if characterradius4.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.estanding = False
        if characterradius5.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.estanding = False
        if characterradius6.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.estanding = False
        if characterradius7.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.estanding = False
```

Here's the full code in case you need it:

```
import pygame
import time
import os
import random

pygame.init()

# Screen Resolution
screen_width = 800
screen_height = 600

# Character Variables
character_x = 380
character_y = 250

# Background Variables
backgroundx = -375
backgroundy = -255

# Images
bgimage = pygame.image.load('bg.png')
characterimage = pygame.image.load('character.png')
characterbackimage = pygame.image.load('characterback.png')
characterleftimage = pygame.image.load('characterright.png')
characterrightimage = pygame.image.load('characterleft.png')

zombieimage = pygame.image.load('zombie.png')
zombieupimage = pygame.image.load('zombieback.png')
zombieleftimage = pygame.image.load('zombieleft.png')
zombierightimage = pygame.image.load('zombieright.png')

healthbarimage = pygame.image.load('healthbar.png')
hungerbarimage = pygame.image.load('hungerbar.png')
thirstbarimage = pygame.image.load('thirstbar.png')
energybarimage = pygame.image.load('energybar.png')

healthimage = pygame.image.load('health.png')
hungerimage = pygame.image.load('hunger.png')
thirstimage = pygame.image.load('thirst.png')

vignetteimage = pygame.image.load('vignette.png')

# Movement Fix
characterbackx = 6.5
characterbacky = 5
characterleftx = 5
characterlefty = 4
characterrightx = 7.5
characterrighty = 4.5

# Bars
healthbarx = 580
healthbary = 555
hungerbarx = 580
hungerbary = 520
thirstbarx = 580
thirstbary = 485
energybarx = 765
energybary = 430

energybardraw_x = 770
energybardraw_y = 432.5
energybardraw_width = 15
energybardraw_height = 1

thirstbardraw_x = 581
thirstbardraw_y = 490.7
thirstbardraw_width = 1
thirstbardraw_height = 15

hungerbardraw_x = 581
hungerbardraw_y = 524
hungerbardraw_width = 1
hungerbardraw_height = 15

thirsttimer = 0
hungertimer = 0
notsprintthirst = True
notsprinthunger = True
sprintthirst = False
sprinthunger = False

# Settings Variables
vignettex = 0
vignettey = 0

# Settings
vignette_on = True
vignette_off = False

# Movement
timerdown = 0
timerup = 0
timerleft = 0
timerright = 0

movingdown = True
movingleft = False
movingright = False
movingup = False

able_to_move = True

moveup = False
movedown = False
moveleft = False
moveright = False
sprint = False
speed = 2.5


def loadinscreen():

    loadingscreen = pygame.image.load('loadingscreen.png')
    os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 80), pygame.NOFRAME)
    bg = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
    bg.fill((0, 244, 0))
    screen.blit(loadingscreen, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(1)

# Tiers / Level Ups


speedtier_1 = True

# Hitboxes Variables

win = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
character = win.blit(characterimage, (character_x, character_y))

class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def draw(self):
        global characterradius, characterradius1, characterradius2, characterradius3, characterradius4, characterradius5
        global characterradius6, characterradius7, estanding, emoveup, emovedown, emoveleft, emoveright, enemyradiusshow
        global eradius1, eradius2, eradius3, eradius4

        self.enemyradiusshow = True
        self.estanding = False
        emoveup = False
        emovedown = False
        emoveleft = False
        emoveright = False

        if moveup:
            self.y += speed
        if movedown:
            self.y -= speed
        if moveleft:
            self.x += speed
        if moveright:
            self.x -= speed

        enemyhitbox = pygame.Rect(self.x + 6, self.y + 5, 50, 80)
        self.enemyhitbox = pygame.Rect(self.x + 6, self.y + 5, 50, 80)
        enemyhitboxvisible = True
        self.enemyhitboxvisible = False
        playerradiusvisible = False

        if self.enemyhitboxvisible:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (self.x + 6, self.y + 5, 50, 80))
        if enemyhitboxvisible:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (self.x + 6, self.y + 5, 50, 80))

        if playerradiusvisible:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (80, 200, 50), (character_x - 180, character_y - 180, 150.5, 150.5))
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (200, 80, 50), (character_x + 80, character_y - 180, 150.5, 150.5))
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (80, 50, 200), (character_x - 180, character_y + 90, 150.5, 150.5))
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (200, 150, 50), (character_x + 80, character_y + 90, 150.5, 150.5))

            pygame.draw.rect(win, (150, 150, 50), (character_x - 180, character_y - 30, 150.5, 120))
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (200, 70, 50), (character_x + 80, character_y - 30, 150.5, 120))
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (50, 150, 200), (character_x - 30, character_y - 180, 110, 150.5))
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (50, 150, 200), (character_x - 30, character_y + 90, 110, 150.5))

        characterradius = pygame.Rect(character_x - 180, character_y - 180, 150.5, 150.5)
        characterradius1 = pygame.Rect(character_x + 80, character_y - 180, 150.5, 150.5)
        characterradius2 = pygame.Rect(character_x - 180, character_y + 90, 150.5, 150.5)
        characterradius3 = pygame.Rect(character_x + 80, character_y + 90, 150.5, 150.5)
        character_hitbox = pygame.Rect(character_x + 80, character_y + 90, 150.5, 150.5)

        characterradius4 = pygame.Rect(character_x - 180, character_y - 30, 150.5, 120)
        characterradius5 = pygame.Rect(character_x + 80, character_y - 30, 150.5, 120)
        characterradius6 = pygame.Rect(character_x - 30, character_y - 180, 110, 150.5)
        characterradius7 = pygame.Rect(character_x - 30, character_y + 90, 110, 150.5)

        self.enemyspeed = 1

        if characterradius.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.x += self.enemyspeed
            self.y += self.enemyspeed
            emoveleft = True
        if characterradius1.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.x -= self.enemyspeed
            self.y += self.enemyspeed
            emoveright = True
        if characterradius2.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.x += self.enemyspeed
            self.y -= self.enemyspeed
            emoveleft = True
        if characterradius3.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.x -= self.enemyspeed
            self.y -= self.enemyspeed
            emoveright = True
        if characterradius4.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.x += self.enemyspeed
            emoveleft = True
        if characterradius5.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.x -= self.enemyspeed
            emoveright = True
        if characterradius6.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.y += self.enemyspeed
            emovedown = True
        if characterradius7.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.y -= self.enemyspeed
            emoveup = True

        if emoveup:
            win.blit(zombieupimage, (self.x, self.y))
            self.emovedown = False
            self.emoveleft = False
            self.emoveright = False
            self.emoveup = True
        if emovedown:
            win.blit(zombieimage, (self.x - 5.5, self.y - 4))
            self.emovedown = True
            self.emoveleft = False
            self.emoveright = False
            self.emoveup = False
        if emoveleft:
            win.blit(zombieleftimage, (self.x, self.y))
            self.emovedown = False
            self.emoveleft = True
            self.emoveright = False
            self.emoveup = False
        if emoveright:
            win.blit(zombierightimage, (self.x, self.y))
            self.emovedown = False
            self.emoveleft = False
            self.emoveright = True
            self.emoveup = False

        if not emoveup:
            self.estanding = True
        if not emovedown:
            self.estanding = True
        if not emoveleft:
            self.estanding = True
        if not emoveright:
            self.estanding = True

        if characterradius.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.estanding = False
        if characterradius1.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.estanding = False
        if characterradius2.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.estanding = False
        if characterradius3.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.estanding = False
        if characterradius4.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.estanding = False
        if characterradius5.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.estanding = False
        if characterradius6.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.estanding = False
        if characterradius7.colliderect(self.enemyhitbox):
            self.estanding = False

        if self.estanding:
            win.blit(zombieimage, (self.x, self.y))

        if self.enemyradiusshow:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (self.x - 11, self.y + 40, 15, 15))
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 255, 0), (self.x + 23.5, self.y + 87, 15, 15))
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 255), (self.x + 58, self.y + 40, 15, 15))
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (155, 155, 155), (self.x + 23.5, self.y - 12, 15, 15))

        eradius1 = pygame.Rect (self.x - 11, self.y + 40, 15, 15)
        eradius2 = pygame.Rect (self.x + 23.5, self.y + 87, 15, 15)
        eradius3 = pygame.Rect (self.x + 58, self.y + 40, 15, 15)
        eradius4 = pygame.Rect (self.x + 23.5, self.y - 12, 15, 15)




enemies = []
randomposx = 500
randomposy = 500
max_enemies = 10
milliseconds_delay = 1
spawn_event = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
enemie_size = zombieimage.get_size()

pygame.time.set_timer(spawn_event, milliseconds_delay)
run = True

while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        elif event.type == spawn_event:
            if len(enemies) < max_enemies:
                x = random.randint(1, randomposx - enemie_size[0])
                y = random.randint(1, randomposy - enemie_size[1])
                e = Enemy(x, y)
                enemies.append(e)

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                moveup = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                movedown = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                moveleft = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                moveright = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LSHIFT:
                sprint = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if able_to_move:
                if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                    moveup = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    movedown = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    moveleft = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                    moveright = False
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LSHIFT:
                    sprint = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    pygame.display.update()

    # Hitboxes

    def background():
        win.blit(bgimage, (backgroundx, backgroundy))

    background()
    for e in enemies:
        e.draw()

    def vignette():
        if vignette_on:
            win.blit(vignetteimage, (vignettex, vignettey))

    vignette()

    class Bars:
        win.blit(healthbarimage, (healthbarx, healthbary))
        win.blit(hungerbarimage, (hungerbarx, hungerbary))
        win.blit(thirstbarimage, (thirstbarx, thirstbary))
        win.blit(energybarimage, (energybarx, energybary))

        win.blit(healthimage, (735, 556.2))
        win.blit(hungerimage, (735, 520.5))
        win.blit(thirstimage, (733.5, 486.6))

    def drawbars():
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 0), (energybardraw_x, energybardraw_y, energybardraw_width, energybardraw_height))
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 0), (thirstbardraw_x, thirstbardraw_y, thirstbardraw_width, thirstbardraw_height))
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 0), (hungerbardraw_x, hungerbardraw_y, hungerbardraw_width, hungerbardraw_height))

    drawbars()

    def hitboxvisible():
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (200, 10, 50), (character_x, character_y, 50, 80))

    if movingdown:
        character = win.blit(characterimage, (character_x, character_y))
    if movingleft:
        characterleft = win.blit(characterleftimage, (character_x + characterleftx, character_y + characterlefty))
    if movingright:
        characterright = win.blit(characterrightimage, (character_x + characterrightx, character_y + characterrighty))
    if movingup:
        characterback = win.blit(characterbackimage, (character_x + characterbackx, character_y + characterbacky))

    if moveup:
        goingdown = False
        movingleft = False
        movingright = False
        movingup = True
        backgroundy += speed
    if movedown:
        movingleft = False
        movingright = False
        movingup = False
        movingdown = True
        backgroundy -= speed
    if moveleft:
        movingdown = False
        movingleft = True
        movingright = False
        movingup = False
        backgroundx += speed
    if moveright:
        movingdown = False
        movingleft = False
        movingright = True
        movingup = False
        backgroundx -= speed

    def energybar_gain():
        global energybardraw_height
        energybardraw_height -= 0.8

    if speedtier_1:
        if sprint:
            speed = 4
            energybardraw_height += 2
            sprintthirst = True
            notsprintthirst = False
            sprinthunger = True
            notsprinthunger = False
        if not sprint:
            speed = 3
            energybar_gain()
            sprintthirst = False
            notsprintthirst = True
            sprinthunger = False
            notsprinthunger = True

        if energybardraw_height < 0:
            energybardraw_height = 1
        if energybardraw_height > 146:
            energybardraw_height = 146
            sprint = False

    if notsprintthirst:
        thirsttimer += 0.5
    if sprintthirst:
        thirsttimer += 1

    if thirsttimer == 150:
        thirstbardraw_width += 2
    if thirsttimer > 150:
        thirsttimer = 0

    if notsprinthunger:
        hungertimer += 0.5
    if sprinthunger:
        hungertimer += 1
    if hungertimer == 175:
        hungerbardraw_width += 2
    if hungertimer > 175:
        hungertimer = 0

    if moveup or movedown or moveleft or moveright:
        timerdown += 1
        if timerdown > 12:
            timerdown = 0

        if timerdown == 1:
            character_y -= 1
        if timerdown == 2:
            character_y -= 1
        if timerdown == 3:
            character_y -= 1
        if timerdown == 4:
            character_y -= 1

        if timerdown == 5:
            character_y += 1
        if timerdown == 6:
            character_y += 1
        if timerdown == 7:
            character_y += 1
        if timerdown == 8:
            character_y += 1

    # Zombies Only

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: I deleted the other accounts this one's here to stay I guess

Comment: Based on your code, I recommend to use objects of type [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) for the hit boxes and [`.colliderect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) for the collision test.

Comment: I have tried that. Yet with no success. Could you please give me an example of how it would work.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a game design question, but typically to prevent sprites from overlapping you detect collision and then set their position to a place that is *just* not overlapping. You might initially think of this as janky teleportation, but if collisions are being detected 30 times every second (framerate), the tiny distance that they teleport will be invisible to the player.

The easiest way to detect collision is to give them a circular hitbox specified by a radius. This isn't a perfect solution, but it will get you on track to optimize and think of a more optimal way that will work for you.

As a side note, I'm not familiar with PyGame, but I'm sure they have some sort of library for Vector math. Vector2 is essentially an array of [self.xPos, self.yPos] with some extra helper functions, like finding distance using the Pythagorean theorem.

The half-pseudocode/half-python looks somewhat like this:

```
for enemy1 in enemies: 
    for enemy2 in enemies:
        if enemy1 == enemy2: #if both are the same enemy
            continue
        # Find the dist between both enemies
        # *Assumes sprite anchor is in center
        distanceBetween = Vector2.DistanceBetween(enemy1, enemy2)  
        combinedHitbox = enemy1.radius + enemy2.radius

        if combinedHitbox < distanceBetween:
            # Calculate the delta position (difference between)
            positionDiff = enemy2.position - enemy1.position
            # Move them away from each other half of the distance between them.
            enemy2.position += positionDiff /2
            enemy1.position -= positionDiff /2
```

PyGame might also have some better way for hitbox detection that will do this behind the scenes, but I think its important that all game developers should at least once try to implement their own just to see how it works.